# Copy FIlestream to new stream giving empty file

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

I'm working on converting some files, but I'm having some issues on the 2nd step of this.

1. Load file from source location
2. Save file to temp folder
3. Save converted file to Output location

I have 2 methods for reading the original file, but there is a problem with both of them.

- Method 1: The file remains locked (so when something goes wrong, I have to restart the app)
- Method 2: The temp file is empty

Anybody got an idea on how to fix one of those problems?

**Utilities class**

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Get document stream
/// </summary>
/// <param name="DocumentName">Input document name</param> 
public static Stream GetDocumentStreamFromLocation(string documentLocation)
{
    try
    {
        //ExStart:GetDocumentStream

        // Method one: works, but locks file
        return File.Open(documentLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Method two: gives empty file on temp folder
        using (FileStream fsSource = File.Open(documentLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream((int)fsSource.Length);
            fsSource.CopyTo(stream);

            return stream;
        }
        //ExEnd:GetDocumentStream
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ioEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ioEx.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Save file in any format
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename">Save as provided string</param>
/// <param name="content">Stream as content of a file</param>
public static void SaveFile(string filename, Stream content, string location = OUTPUT_PATH)
{
    try
    {
        //ExStart:SaveAnyFile
        //Create file stream
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(location), filename)))
        {

            content.CopyTo(fileStream);

        }
        //ExEnd:SaveAnyFile
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I Call the following functions as following:

```cs
public static StreamContent Generate(string sourceLocation)
{
    // Get filename
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceLocation);
    // Create tempfilename
    var tempFilename = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}_{fileName}";

    // Put file in storage location
    Utilities.SaveFile(tempFilename, Utilities.GetDocumentStreamFromLocation(sourceLocation), Utilities.STORAGE_PATH);

    // ... More code
}
```

Comment: Try `fsSource.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before starting the `CopyTo`. IIRC the Open method points the Seek position to the end of the file.

Comment: Do you need to do any processing of the data before making a copy? As in, are you working on a copy of the source or the stream itself?

Comment: @Fabulous I'm working on a copy of the document

Comment: @MarkusDeibel That didn't work

Comment: For making a copy I would recommend the `File.Copy(string, string)` method that will make the copy for you then you can open that stream and work on it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy the source file to a temp folder, the easiest way is to use the `File.Copy` method from the `System.IO` namespace. Consider the following:

```
// Assuming the variables have been set as you already had, this creates a copy in the intended location.
File.Copy(documentLocation, filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging. I found out that you can add a property in the File.Open that "fixes" this issue:

`return File.Open(documentLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);`

With the downside that you still can't move / rename the file, but the lock is removed.